# Customized table section header does not work

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I created a customized section header with the following code, but the red label did not show.

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];

    UILabel * label1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label1.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [headerView addSubview:label1];

    return headerView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designated initializer for `UILabel` is `-initWithFrame:` and not `-init`. Your label isn't appearing because you have not specified a frame for the view.

Additionally, I noticed that you haven't initialized `headerView` with a frame either, but that appears to be working because the `UITableView` is probably setting a new frame at some point. You should get in the habit of using the designated initializer.

[UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCDCECG)